# Html5 notification

Tags: javascript, html5, уведомления

```
Notification.requestPermission(function(permission){
    // переменная permission содержит результат запроса
    console.log('Результат запроса прав:', permission);
    //default — запрос на получение прав не отправлялся
    //granted — пользователь разрешил показывать уведомления
    //denied — пользователь запретил показывать уведомления
});

var notification = new Notification('Тема уведомления',
    { body: 'Тело уведомления', dir: 'auto', icon: 'icon.jpg', tag: "333" }
);
```

Можно ли отсылать уведомления пользователю если у него закрыт сайт? И как?

Comment: Сомнительно. Разве что пользователь установит ваш плагин для браузера. А вообще думаю правильней использовать что-то готовое, что уже есть у множества пользователей например Telegram

Answer (score 1):

Notification — работает только если сайт открыт.

Смотрите в сторону Push API — [Пример](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notifications-on-the-open-web) [Информация](http://w3c.github.io/push-api/)

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то нужен ключ API от Google, что бы всё работало? Ключ платный на сколько я знаю.